# Mysql Stored Procedure. Any issue with this one?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, printing

Here is the stored proc. What I am trying to do is to loop through all databases and find a count of rows in a particular table. If count is 0, then print the table.

```
  DELIMITER $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE checkTableData()
  BEGIN
     DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE db VARCHAR(255);
     DECLARE appDBs CURSOR FOR SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE     schema_name LIKE 'db_%';
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
     DECLARE intCount INT default;

     OPEN appDBs;
     REPEAT
        FETCH appDBs INTO db;
          IF NOT done THEN
              SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT @intCount = COUNT(1) FROM ', db, '.SMS_CODES');
              EXECUTE @SQL;
              IF @intCount = 0 THEN
                 SELECT  db;
              END IF;    
         END IF;    
     UNTIL done END REPEAT;

     CLOSE appDBs;
  END $$
  delimiter ;
```

The error is at the line

```
  IF NOT done THEN
```

Edit:
  Tried `IF done != 0 THEN`. The error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL; Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ;

     OPEN appDBs;
     REPEAT
        FETCH appDBs INTO db;
              `IF don' at line 7
```

Edit:
  Per @Gerve I updated the proc and moved the intCount declaration to top, above cursor, and then set it to 0. So that error is gone. Now another error is at:

```
 You have an error in your SQL; Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version     for the right syntax to use near '@SQL 
 @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT @intCount = COUNT(1) FROM ', db, '.ECR_SMS_COUNTRY_CODES');
            EXECUTE @SQL;
    END IF;         
 UNTIL done END REPEAT;
     CLOSE appDBs;
  EN' at line 15
```

Comment: What's the error msg?

Comment: `done` is an int, did you try done=0 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First Error***

```
DECLARE intCount INT default;
```

No default value, just change it to:

```
DECLARE intCount INT default 0;
```

- MySQL says the error is *near*, that means just before.

***Second Error***

The second error is caused because you can't execute a string, you need to prepare a statement first: [Prepare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html), [Execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html)

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. That error is gone. But there is another error. `for the right syntax to use near @SQL`

Comment: Is the statement `intCount = count(*) FROM` correct? It does not seem to return anything.